# Cygwin Usr Local Directory Structure

Tags: cygwin

I currently have the folder structure shown below.
[image]

The include file apparently does not belong, since it does not exist in an earlier cygwin directory I had backed up.
Also, I continually get this warning :

> cc1plus: warning: /usr/local/include: not a directory

**Should I delete this file**, because I believe it is preventing an include directory from being created during builds.

Comment: the `include` directory under `/usr/local` should be a normal one. You can delete it or just rename

Comment: Delete or rename the file, of course. Okay, thanks.